# Manipulating audio in React Native? (Specifically trimming)

Tags: react-native

Sorry to bother you, everyone. I'm currently developing an application in which I need to take an audio file and programmatically trim the audio file and save it, but I reached a dead-end when I couldn't find any modules online for audio manipulation. All online examples are for recording audio, but what I need is to access an audio file from storage and then trim it.
Did anyone run through a similar experience and would be able to help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no such package for react-native. But you can still use npm packages such as sox-audio or, audio-buffer-utils for audio manipulations.

Resources:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-buffer-utils

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox-audio

Comment: Oh, thanks a bunch! I'll definitely give those a try :)

Comment: did you give it a try ? Worth to spend time on that ? @beta4attack

Comment: @beta4attack Is this worth pending time on?

Comment: Ended up writing a module to support trimming on iOS. Check it out! (https://github.com/thehanimo/react-native-audiokit)

Comment: is there any other module which works on both android and ios

Comment: i was not able to install sox-audio in my react-native project. was someone able to install it?

Answer (score 1):

[This module](https://github.com/thehanimo/react-native-audiokit) can help you trim audio files with react-native on iOS.